# Create a MongoDB user from commandline

Tags: mongodb

I have set up a MongoDB database with an `admin` user that has only administrative rights, not read or write access to databases.

What I now would want to do is:

- Add a new database,
- and add a new user to that database.

And: I need to do this from the command line. So I tried:

```
$ mongo admin -u admin -p admin --eval "db.addUser('dummyuser', 'dummysecret')"
```

(Please note that as I am still running MongoDB 2.0, I am using the old format of `db.addUser`.)

This would make perfect sense if I could also tell it which database this user should be for. But now I am struggling. How do I specify the database for this command? If I were in the interactive shell, I could just run

```
> use dummydb
```

but how do I do this from the command line? My first try was to concatenate both commands with a `;`, but this didn't work:

```
$ mongo admin -u admin -p admin --eval "use dummydb;db.addUser('dummyuser', 'dummysecret')"
```

just gives me syntax error.

How do I get this right?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `use db` syntax is only supported in an interactive shell session.

If you want to change databases from an admin script, you can use [`db.getSiblingDB('dbname')`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/).

So your equivalent command line using `--eval` would be:

```
# MongoDB 2.6+: use createUser()
$ mongo admin -u admin -p admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('dummydb').createUser({user: 'dummyuser', pwd: 'dummysecret', roles: ['readWrite']})"

# MongoDB 2.4: use addUser()
$ mongo admin -u admin -p admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('dummydb').addUser('dummyuser', 'dummysecret')"
```

There is a section in the MongoDB manual covering [Differences between interactive and scripted `mongo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo). This includes equivalents for other interactive shell helpers such as `show dbs` and `show collections`.

Comment: this does not work. [collectionName] is not defined, even though it clearly is

Comment: @Tyguy7 Can you please create a new question with details of what you tried and your environment (specific version of MongoDB shell & server)? The answer you are commenting on is from more than 5 years ago and makes no reference to `[collectionName]`. Thanks!

Comment: @Tyguy7 FYI, I also updated the example here with syntax for modern versions of MongoDB that use [`db.createUser()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/) instead of the older (and now removed) `db.addUser()` shell helper.

Answer (score 7):

Solved it by putting the commands

```
use dummydb
db.addUser('dummyuser', 'dummysecret')
```

into a `.js` file, and then ran MongoDB by calling:

```
$ mongo admin -u admin -p admin < setupMongoDB.js
```

That's it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Above in my case didn't worked

```
use dummyDb

db.createUser({user: "admin",pwd: "secrectP@wd",roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "reporting" } ],mechanisms: [ "SCRAM-SHA-256" ]   }
```