# Create a user in MongoDB using command line

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, terminal

I have a pipeline that executes commands and I want to use it to add a user to MongoDB. I have seen similar answers on stackoverflow, but those are for an older MongoDB version (they use `.addUser()` instead of `.createUser()`).

So far I have tried this:

```
'mongo {AUTH_URL} admin --eval "db.createUser({ createUser: {DB_USERNAME}, pwd: {DB_USER_PASSWORD}, roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: {DB_NAME}}]})'
```

So what i need is a single line of code that will create the user for me and i will set all of the necessary elements through environment variables. 
If someone could provide an example of a terminal command to create a new user that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a MongoDB user from commandline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682891/create-a-mongodb-user-from-commandline)

Comment: You've got a line of code which looks like it can add a user - what goes wrong when you run it?

Answer (score 12):

1. install mongodb3.0
2. `mongo`
3. `use admin`
4. `db.createUser({user:'admin',pwd:'admin',roles:
       [{role:'root',db:'admin'}]})`
5. `use newdatabase`
6. `db.createUser({user:'database_user',pwd:'newdatabasepass',roles:[{role:'readWrite',db:'newdatabase'}]})`

Answer (score 1):

As per the document given you need to pass values like this.

```
db.createUser({user: "<username>",pwd: "<password>", roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "<dbName>" }, "clusterAdmin"]})
```

As this is as per the latest documentation.

Comment: so what i do is `mongo db.createUser({user: "<username>",pwd: "<password>", roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "<dbName>" }, "clusterAdmin"]})
`

Comment: Login to mongo console and then type use dbname; then run the above command

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Open _MONGOSH[image]

```
db.createUser({user:'user',pwd:'P@ss909',roles:[{role:'readWrite',db:'UseDB'}]})
```

Click Enter, You will get Return response as OK
[image]